# how can i find a timestamp value in a table based on a date provided

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, query-optimization

I have a database where the date_added fields are timestamp. I want to make a query and select some products that were added on a certain day. 
Let's say:
`tbl_products:
    id INT 
    name VARCHAR
    date_added TIMESTAMP`

The query:
`SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE date_added = ?` where ? is the param that I am sending. I can send it as a date or a timestamp.

The matches need to be after days. I mean I need to find products added in a certain day.

edit: I am using oracle database

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: A certain Day as in Monday, tuesday, wednesday.....?? or as in May 5th?

Comment: a certain day is 05, 11,

Answer (score 2):

You've basically got two choices...

The efficient way (will use index if one exists on date_added column):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_products
WHERE date_added between ? and ?
```

Provide timestamps based on the date at `00:00:00` and `23:59:59` for the query parameters

Similar to the above, this might work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_products
WHERE date_added between ? + interval '0' second and ? + interval '86399' second
```

Providing the date twice.

The easy (but inefficient - won't use index) way:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE date(date_added) = ?
```

Provide the date as the parameter

Comment: i pass date .. how can i match this with timestamp? i have timestamp in my table

Comment: @Mythriel Read the edited answer. And which DB are you using? mysql? oracle? what?

Comment: @Mythriel Try the (new) second option in the answer

Comment: @Bohemian: remember that for a `timestamp`, `23:59:59` is *not* the latest timestamp in a day.